# How to get the value of a selected radio button

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I want to get the selected value from a group of radio buttons.

Here's my HTML:

```html
<div id="rates">
  <input type="radio" id="r1" name="rate" value="Fixed Rate"> Fixed Rate
  <input type="radio" id="r2" name="rate" value="Variable Rate"> Variable Rate
  <input type="radio" id="r3" name="rate" value="Multi Rate" checked="checked"> Multi Rate
</div>
```

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
var rates = document.getElementById('rates').value;
var rate_value;
if(rates == 'Fixed Rate'){
    rate_value = document.getElementById('r1').value;

}else if(rates == 'Variable Rate'){
    rate_value = document.getElementById('r2').value;

}else if(rates == 'Multi Rate'){
    rate_value = document.getElementById('r3').value;
}

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = rate_value;
```

I keep getting *undefined*.

Comment: You're not using jQuery here, but if you ever wanted to, you could use this: `$("input[type='radio'][name='rate']:checked").val();`

Comment: Why can't you inspect that object? Anyway you need to use `.checked`

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting selected value of radio button in case of action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492928/getting-selected-value-of-radio-button-in-case-of-action)

Comment: I'm not sure if that is required or not, but it is a good habit to put radio buttons in `<form></form>` container.

Comment: Why do you expect a `<div>` to have the checked and value properties?

Answer (score 323, accepted):

```
var rates = document.getElementById('rates').value;
```

The rates element is a `div`, so it won't have a value. This is probably where the `undefined` is coming from.

The `checked` property will tell you whether the element is selected:

```
if (document.getElementById('r1').checked) {
  rate_value = document.getElementById('r1').value;
}
```

Or

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='rate']:checked").val();
```

Comment: mahdavipanah's code just above (with `[checked]`) looks for the *attribute* (i.e. initial state). You should instead use `:checked`, which looks for the *property* (i.e. current state), and which is almost always what you want.

Comment: In Javascript, you don't need to get _all_ of them though: `document.querySelector("input[name=rate]:checked").value`.

Answer (score 766):

This works in IE9 and above and all other browsers.

```
document.querySelector('input[name="rate"]:checked').value;
```

Comment: Of course you would have to check if querySelector returns null. This is the case if no radio button is checked.

Comment: Note that the quotation marks around `rate` are not required.

Answer (score 163):

You can get the value by using the `checked` property.

```
var rates = document.getElementsByName('rate');
var rate_value;
for(var i = 0; i < rates.length; i++){
    if(rates[i].checked){
        rate_value = rates[i].value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that only one radio can be checked, I'd normally expect a `break` or `return` statement inside the `if` block to stop additional passes through the loop. A minor point, but good style.

Answer (score 54):

For you people living on the edge:

There is now something called a [RadioNodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RadioNodeList) and accessing its value property will return the value of the currently checked input. This will remove the necessity of first filtering out the 'checked' input as we see in many of the posted answers.

Example Form

```
<form id="test">
    <label><input type="radio" name="test" value="A"> A</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="test" value="B" checked> B</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="test" value="C"> C</label>
</form>
```

To retrieve the checked value, you could do something like this:

```
var form = document.getElementById("test");
alert(form.elements["test"].value);
```

The JSFiddle to prove it: http://jsfiddle.net/vjop5xtq/

Please note this was implemented in Firefox 33 (all other major browser seems to support it). Older browsers will require a [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) for `RadioNodeList` for this to properly function.

Comment: `form.elements["test"].value` works very well in Chrome[Version 49.0.2623.87 m].

Comment: It has to be a form, can't use e.g. a div. Otherwise this is working in FF 71.0.

Answer (score 34):

If you are using JavaScript without jQuery, you can use this command:

```
document.querySelector("input[type='radio'][name=rate]:checked").value;
```

Comment: That works, we can more simplify, if you're sure the input element name `document.querySelector("input[name='rate']:checked")`

Answer (score 17):

The one worked for me is given below from api.jquery.com.

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="option" value="o1">option1</input>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="o2">option2</input>
```

JavaScript

```
var selectedOption = $("input:radio[name=option]:checked").val()
```

The variable selectedOption will contain the value of the selected radio button (i.e) o1 or o2

Answer (score 16):

Another (apparently older) option is to use the format:
"document.nameOfTheForm.nameOfTheInput.value;"
e.g. **document.mainForm.rads.value;**

```js
document.mainForm.onclick = function(){
    var radVal = document.mainForm.rads.value;
    result.innerHTML = 'You selected: '+radVal;
}
```

```html
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">
    <input type="radio" name="rads" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="rads" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="rads" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="rads" value="4" />
</form>
<span id="result"></span>
```

You can refer to the element by its name within a form. Your original HTML does not contain a form element though.

Fiddle here (works in Chrome and Firefox):
https://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Shields/23kg3tf4/1/

Comment: The fiddle above doesn't seem to work with the Safari browser (7.1.4). The value shows as undefined, changing the radio button states does not affect that.

Comment: Yes, this also doesn't work with Edge browser (40.15063.0.0). If they deprecated this way, it seems strange, because this way is simpler and makes sense since radio buttons are grouped by their nature. Most of the other answers look just like they are checking checkboxes.

Answer (score 14):

Use **document.querySelector('input[type = radio]:checked').value;** to get the value of the selected checkbox. You can use other attributes to get value like **name = gender**, etc. Please go through the below snippet. Definitely it will helpful to you.

Solution

```js
document.mainForm.onclick = function(){
    var gender = document.querySelector('input[name = gender]:checked').value;
    result.innerHTML = 'You Gender: '+gender;
}
```

```html
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" checked/>Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" />Female
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Others" />Others
</form>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 11):

##### HTML code

```html
<input type="radio" name="rdoName" value="YES"/>
<input type="radio" name="rdoName" value="NO"/>
```

##### jQuery code

```
var value = $("input:radio[name=rdoName]:checked").val();
```

```js
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    var value = $("input:radio[name=rdoName]:checked").val();
    console.log(value);
    alert(value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="rdoName" value="YES"/> YES
<input type="radio" name="rdoName" value="NO"/> NO
<br/>
<input type="button"id="btnSubmit"value="Which one Selected"/>
```

You will get

```
value="YES" // If checked Radio Button with the value "YES"
value="NO" // If checked Radio Button with the value "NO"
```

Answer (score 8):

## Shortest

```
[...rates.children].find(c=>c.checked).value
```

```js
let v= [...rates.children].find(c=>c.checked).value

console.log(v);
```

```html
<div id="rates">
  <input type="radio" id="r1" name="rate" value="Fixed Rate"> Fixed Rate
  <input type="radio" id="r2" name="rate" value="Variable Rate"> Variable Rate
  <input type="radio" id="r3" name="rate" value="Multi Rate" checked="checked"> Multi Rate  
</div>
```

Comment: By the way... `document.rates.rate.value` is lot shorter, more intuitive and works like a charm

Comment: @WΩLLE-ˈvɔlə your code not works - I check it with question html and it thorws exception `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined"` because `reates.rate` is undefined

Answer (score 6):

In Javascript we can get the values by using Id's "**`getElementById()`**" in the above code you posted has contain name not Id 
so you to modify like this

```
if (document.getElementById('r1').checked) {
  rate_value = document.getElementById('r1').value;
}
```

use this rate_value according to your code

Answer (score 5):

A year or so has passed since the question was asked, but I thought a substantial improvement of the answers was possible. I find this the easiest and most versatile script, because it checks whether a button has been checked, and if so, what its value is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Check radio checked and its value</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="theFormName">
        <input type="radio" name="theRadioGroupName" value="10">
        <input type="radio" name="theRadioGroupName" value="20">
        <input type="radio" name="theRadioGroupName" value="30">
        <input type="radio" name="theRadioGroupName" value="40">
        <input type="button" value="Check" onclick="getRadioValue('theRadioGroupName')">
    </form>

    <script>
        function getRadioValue(groupName) {
            var radios = theFormName.elements[groupName];
            window.rdValue; // declares the global variable 'rdValue'
            for (var i=0; i<radios.length; i++) {
                var someRadio = radios[i];
                if (someRadio.checked) {
                    rdValue = someRadio.value;
                    break;
                }
                else rdValue = 'noRadioChecked';
            }
            if (rdValue == '10') {
                alert('10'); // or: console.log('10')
            }
            else if (rdValue == 'noRadioChecked') {
                alert('no radio checked');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also call the function within another function, like this:

```
function doSomething() {
    getRadioValue('theRadioGroupName');
    if (rdValue == '10') {
        // do something
    }
    else if (rdValue == 'noRadioChecked') {
        // do something else
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Directly calling a radio button many times gives you the value of the *first* button, not the *checked* button.  Instead of looping through radio buttons to see which one is checked, I prefer to call an `onclick` JavaScript function that sets a variable that can later be retrieved at will.

```
<input type="radio" onclick="handleClick(this)" name="reportContent" id="reportContent" value="/reportFleet.php" >
```

Which calls:

```
var currentValue = 0;
function handleClick(myRadio) {
    currentValue = myRadio.value;
    document.getElementById("buttonSubmit").disabled = false;
}
```

An additional advantage being that I can treat data and/or react to the checking of a button (in this case, enabling the *submit* button).

Comment: you should bind the `onchange` event instead, in cases the user uses a keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

An improvement to the previous suggested functions:

```
function getRadioValue(groupName) {
    var _result;
    try {
        var o_radio_group = document.getElementsByName(groupName);
        for (var a = 0; a < o_radio_group.length; a++) {
            if (o_radio_group[a].checked) {
                _result = o_radio_group[a].value;
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (e) { }
    return _result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also loop through the buttons with a forEach-loop on the elements

```
    var elements = document.getElementsByName('radioButton');
    var checkedButton;
    console.log(elements);
    elements.forEach(e => {
        if (e.checked) {
            //if radio button is checked, set sort style
            checkedButton = e.value;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want it to fail if no value is checked yet, you can use the [Optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.`:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="rate"]:checked')?.value
```

Optional chaining operator works in 92.35% of the browsers as per writing of this post August 22 2023 as per [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.find()` to select checked element:

```
var radio = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#rate input'))

var value = radio.length && radio.find(r => r.checked).value
```

Comment: I didn't know Array.find, love it! But this would break if no element is checked.

Answer (score 2):

My take on this problem with pure JavaScript is to find the checked node, find its value and pop it out from the array.

```
var Anodes = document.getElementsByName('A'),
    AValue = Array.from(Anodes)
       .filter(node => node.checked)
       .map(node => node.value)
       .pop();
console.log(AValue);
```

Note that I'm using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7kjpc2ue/) for a working example.

Comment: I would add a `tagName === 'INPUT'` check to make sure you're not working on any tags other than `input`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution putting the radio buttons in a constant and getting the selected value only when needed.

```js
const rates = document.forms.rates.elements["rate"]
showRate()
function showRate(){
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = rates.value
}
```

```html
<form id="rates" onchange="showRate()">
  <input type="radio" id="r1" name="rate" value="Fixed Rate"> Fixed Rate
  <input type="radio" id="r2" name="rate" value="Variable Rate"> Variable Rate
  <input type="radio" id="r3" name="rate" value="Multi Rate" checked="checked"> Multi Rate 
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form id="rates">
  <input type="radio" name="rate" value="Fixed Rate"> Fixed
  <input type="radio" name="rate" value="Variable Rate"> Variable
  <input type="radio" name="rate" value="Multi Rate" checked> Multi
</form>
```

then...

```
var rate_value = rates.rate.value;
```

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question?

Comment: "_get the selected value from a group of radio buttons_": `rates.rate.value` not `rates.value`

Comment: This is a correct answer. `document.getElementById("rates").rate.value` [or] `document.forms[0].rate.value`

Answer (score 0):

Check a value by ID:

```
var CheckedValues = ($("#r1").is(':checked')) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the *[jQuery.click](https://api.jquery.com/click/)* function to get the desired output:

```
$('input[name=rate]').click(function(){
  console.log('Hey you clicked this: ' + this.value);

  if(this.value == 'Fixed Rate'){
    rate_value = $('#r1').value;
  } else if(this.value =='Variable Rate'){
    rate_value = $('#r2').value;
  } else if(this.value =='Multi Rate'){
    rate_value = $('#r3').value;
  }

  $('#results').innerHTML = rate_value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the buttons are in a form
`var myform = new FormData(getformbywhatever);
myform.get("rate");`
QuerySelector above is a better solution. However, this method is easy to understand, especially if you don't have a clue about CSS. Plus, input fields are quite likely to be in a form anyway.
Didn't check, there are other similar solutions, sorry for the repetition

Answer (score 0):

```
var rates = document.getElementById('rates').value;
```

cannot get values of a radio button like that instead use

```
rate_value = document.getElementById('r1').value;
```

Comment: to get values of an HTML tag use  document.getElementById('r1').innerHtml

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jQuery, please use the bellow snippet for group of radio buttons.

```
var radioBtValue = $('input[type=radio][name=radiobt]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use: `document.querySelector('input[rate][checked]').value`

Comment: Did not work for me; see a similar syntax above from Pawan that did. As in, `document.querySelector('input[name = rate]:checked').value`

Answer (score -1):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQxbZJ

The HTML

```html
<div id="rates">
    <input type="radio" id="x1" name="rate" value="Fixed Rate"> Fixed Rate
    <input type="radio" id="x2" name="rate" value="Variable Rate"
           checked="checked"> Variable Rate
    <input type="radio" id="x3" name="rate" value="Multi Rate" > Multi Rate
</div>

<button id="rdio"> Check Radio </button>
<div id="check">

</div>
```

The JavaScript

```
var x, y;
var x = document.getElementById("check");
function boom()
{
  if (document.getElementById("x1").checked)
    y = document.getElementById("x1").value;
  
  else if(document.getElementById("x2").checked)
    y = document.getElementById("x2").value;
  
  else if (document.getElementById("x3").checked)
    y = document.getElementById("x3").value;

  else
    y = "kuch nhi;"

  x.innerHTML = y;
}

var z = document.getElementById('rdio');
z.addEventListener("click", boom);`
```

Comment: Is the backtick at the end actually part of it?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*