# Get text node from checked radio button

Tags: javascript

Here is a piece of html for a radio button that is currently selected:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="reason" value="1" data-promo="1">
    "some text here bla bla"
</label>
```

With a line of JS I found over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839169/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button) I am able to grab the input element but not the text:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="reason"]:checked');
```

Returns:

```
<input type="radio" name="reason" value="1" data-promo="1">
```

How would I grab the text that follows this element "some text here bla bla"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't know the position of the text in advance, then the simpliest option is to access the [`textContent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of the parent `label` element:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="reason"]:checked').parentElement.textContent;
```

Of course, this assumes that is the only text node in the `label` element.

---

Alternatively, if the text always appears *after* the `input` element, then you could just access the `textContent` property of the [next sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling):

```
document.querySelector('input[name="reason"]:checked').nextSibling.textContent;
```

Answer (score 4):

The text node is the next sibling of the checkbox so

```js
function test() {
  var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[name="reason"]:checked');
  if (checkbox) {
    var text = checkbox.nextSibling.textContent;
    alert(text);
  }
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="reason" value="1" data-promo="1">text 1
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="reason" value="2" data-promo="2">text 2
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="reason" value="3" data-promo="3">text 3
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="reason" value="4" data-promo="4">text 4
</label>
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to using javascript as you do then try this-

```
alert(document.querySelector('input[name="reason"]:checked').nextSibling.textContent);
```

You may do something like this using jQuery as well,

```
$('input[name="reason"]').on("click", function(){
    alert($(this).closest("label").text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a small change to the your code.
Added `data-txt` and used `getAttribute`

```
var a = document.querySelector('input[name="reason"]:checked').getAttribute("data-txt");
alert(a);
```

Check how this works for you.