# Get the checkbox values by using radiobutton click in javascript

Tags: jsf

How can I get values from check boxes by clicking the radio button?

I have three check boxes:

- upc
- price
- sku

I have one radio button **"selected check boxes"**. When I click the radio button I want the values of selected check boxes.

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "radio button"? Normally that means [something like a set of checkboxes but you can only select one at a time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button). It's not something you'd generally click to perform an action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can look to this amazing example [JSF 2 radio buttons example](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-radio-buttons-example/).

You will care about two points in your `radioButton`: the `itemValue` (it's the real value that you send to your JSF managedBean) and the `itemLabel` (it's the value that the user see).

about how to perform something like that (in JavaScript) you can learn about it [How to get value of selected radio button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839169/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button)

Hope that helped you.