# Get radio button value in selection list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML and Javascript code to get selected option value checked in radio button.

instead of this i need reverse, means need to get radio button checked value in select options.

Thanks for your help in Advance....

Here is my code

```
<form name="myform" action="">
<label for="select_value" onchange="myFunction()">
<select name="select_value">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<label for="radio_value">Select Position</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="First">First
<input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Second">Second
<input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Third">Third
<input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Fourth">Fourth
<input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Fifth">Fifth
</form>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("select_value").value;
    document.getElementsByName('radio_value')[x].checked = true;
}
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
select.onchange = function (event) {
    var btns = document.querySelectorAll('[name^="radio_value"]');
    btns[event.target.value].checked = true
}
</script>
```

Comment: [`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)  returns a live NodeList Collection

Comment: How can i get radio button value in selection options?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value of selected radio button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839169/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button)

Comment: i think there is no close tag for input </input>

Comment: Try making a jsFiddle or something - that can better show what you want - something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/b56aLnnz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose all your radio buttons inside a div and add an `onclick` listener like  this :

```
<form name="myform" action="">

<label for="select_value" onchange="myFunction()">Select Number</label>




<select id="select_value">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<label for="radio_value">Select Position</label>
<div onclick="myFunction()">
<input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="First">First</input>
<input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Second">Second</input>
<input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Third">Third</input>
<input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Fourth">Fourth</input>
<input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Fifth">Fifth</input>
</div>
</form>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByName('radio_value');
    for(var i = 0;i < buttons.length;i ++) {
        if(buttons[i].checked == true) document.getElementById('select_value').value = i;
    }
}
</script>
```

This is not a perfect solution.But a simple workaround for your need.

Comment: This is what i exactly needed, Thanks for the answer @vinoth.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the `select` **index** based on the radio buttons selected **index** and not value, you can use this little function `getCheckedRadioIndex` to get the current selected radio index, and then just programatically select the option inside the `onclick` event for the radios.

```js
function getCheckedRadioIndex(radios) {
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++)
    if (radios[i].checked) return i;
}

var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=radio_value]');
var options = document.querySelectorAll('select[name=select_value]>option');

for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  radios[i].onclick = function(event) {
    var index = getCheckedRadioIndex(radios);
    options[index].selected = 'selected';
  };
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" action="">
  <label for="select_value">Select Number</label>

  <select name="select_value">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <label for="radio_value">Select Position</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="First">First
  <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Second">Second
  <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Third">Third
  <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Fourth">Fourth
  <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Fifth">Fifth
</form>
```