# Radio Button's not changing form in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

We have a form on our site (ex. [T-Shirt](https://madcapcoffee.com/shop/apparel/classic-v-neck-tee/)) that changes based on which radio button you select. I wrote a JS function that pairs the mobile dropdown and desktop radio buttons. While visually everything works, the add to cart functionality only works on desktop and not on mobile.

When I ran the forms through a diffchecker, what I noticed was the only lines that changed were the price displayed and the `value` of the `<input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id">`.

Currently the dropdown adds the `attr` of `checked` to the corresponding radio button, which works for display purposes, but I'm learned the form doesn't actually care whether or not the radio button is `checked`.

I'm not sure what the form is looking for. I've tried passing a `click()` to the radio `input` and its also `label`. I even tried manually changing the `.variation_id` from say `652` to `653`. But nothing changed. The form didn't process.

Are there attributes that JS looks for in a radio button that you can't see in the markup?

Here's a form with one option selected:

```html
<div class="av-woo-purchase-button  avia-builder-el-16  el_after_av_hr  avia-builder-el-last "><p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>25.00</span></p>
<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="651" data-product_variations="[{&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;attribute_size&quot;:&quot;Extra Large&quot;},&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;<p class=\&quot;stock in-stock\&quot;>In stock<\/p>\n&quot;,&quot;backorders_allowed&quot;:false,&quot;dimensions&quot;:&quot;N\/A&quot;,&quot;dimensions_html&quot;:&quot;N\/A&quot;,&quot;display_price&quot;:25,&quot;display_regular_price&quot;:25,&quot;image&quot;:{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina.png&quot;,&quot;alt&quot;:&quot;Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina&quot;,&quot;src&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-450x431.png&quot;,&quot;srcset&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-450x431.png 450w, https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-300x288.png 300w, https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-768x736.png 768w, https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-505x484.png 505w, https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina.png 960w&quot;,&quot;sizes&quot;:&quot;(max-width: 450px) 100vw, 450px&quot;,&quot;full_src&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina.png&quot;,&quot;full_src_w&quot;:960,&quot;full_src_h&quot;:920,&quot;thumb_src&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-120x120.png&quot;,&quot;thumb_src_w&quot;:120,&quot;thumb_src_h&quot;:120,&quot;src_w&quot;:450,&quot;src_h&quot;:431},&quot;image_id&quot;:&quot;5823&quot;,&quot;is_downloadable&quot;:false,&quot;is_in_stock&quot;:true,&quot;is_purchasable&quot;:true,&quot;is_sold_individually&quot;:&quot;no&quot;,&quot;is_virtual&quot;:false,&quot;max_qty&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;min_qty&quot;:1,&quot;price_html&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sku&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;variation_description&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;variation_id&quot;:652,&quot;variation_is_active&quot;:true,&quot;variation_is_visible&quot;:true,&quot;weight&quot;:&quot;.3 lbs&quot;,&quot;weight_html&quot;:&quot;.3 lbs&quot;,&quot;step&quot;:1,&quot;input_value&quot;:1},{&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;attribute_size&quot;:&quot;Large&quot;},&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;<p class=\&quot;stock in-stock\&quot;>In stock<\/p>\n&quot;,&quot;backorders_allowed&quot;:false,&quot;dimensions&quot;:&quot;N\/A&quot;,&quot;dimensions_html&quot;:&quot;N\/A&quot;,&quot;display_price&quot;:25,&quot;display_regular_price&quot;:25,&quot;image&quot;:{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina.png&quot;,&quot;alt&quot;:&quot;Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina&quot;,&quot;src&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-450x431.png&quot;,&quot;srcset&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-450x431.png 450w, https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-300x288.png 300w, https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-768x736.png 768w, https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-505x484.png 505w, https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina.png 960w&quot;,&quot;sizes&quot;:&quot;(max-width: 450px) 100vw, 450px&quot;,&quot;full_src&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina.png&quot;,&quot;full_src_w&quot;:960,&quot;full_src_h&quot;:920,&quot;thumb_src&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-120x120.png&quot;,&quot;thumb_src_w&quot;:120,&quot;thumb_src_h&quot;:120,&quot;src_w&quot;:450,&quot;src_h&quot;:431},&quot;image_id&quot;:&quot;5823&quot;,&quot;is_downloadable&quot;:false,&quot;is_in_stock&quot;:true,&quot;is_purchasable&quot;:true,&quot;is_sold_individually&quot;:&quot;no&quot;,&quot;is_virtual&quot;:false,&quot;max_qty&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;min_qty&quot;:1,&quot;price_html&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sku&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;variation_description&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;variation_id&quot;:653,&quot;variation_is_active&quot;:true,&quot;variation_is_visible&quot;:true,&quot;weight&quot;:&quot;.3 lbs&quot;,&quot;weight_html&quot;:&quot;.3 lbs&quot;,&quot;step&quot;:1,&quot;input_value&quot;:1}]" current-image="5823">
 
   <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
         <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="size">Size</label></td>
            <td class="value">
       <div class="desktop-only" id="radio"><div><input type="radio" name="attribute_size" value="Small" id="size_v_Small" disabled="disabled"><label for="size_v_Small">Small</label><input type="hidden" name="radio_variation_id" value="655"><input type="hidden" class="add-to-cart-url" value="https://madcapcoffee.com/?add-to-cart=651&amp;variation_id=655&amp;attribute_size=Small"></div><div><input type="radio" name="attribute_size" value="Medium" id="size_v_Medium" disabled="disabled"><label for="size_v_Medium">Medium</label><input type="hidden" name="radio_variation_id" value="654"><input type="hidden" class="add-to-cart-url" value="https://madcapcoffee.com/?add-to-cart=651&amp;variation_id=654&amp;attribute_size=Medium"></div><div><input type="radio" name="attribute_size" value="Large" id="size_v_Large" checked="checked"><label for="size_v_Large">Large</label><input type="hidden" name="radio_variation_id" value="653"><input type="hidden" class="add-to-cart-url" value="https://madcapcoffee.com/?add-to-cart=651&amp;variation_id=653&amp;attribute_size=Large"></div><div><input type="radio" name="attribute_size" value="Extra Large" id="size_v_Extra Large"><label for="size_v_Extra Large">Extra Large</label><input type="hidden" name="radio_variation_id" value="652"><input type="hidden" class="add-to-cart-url" value="https://madcapcoffee.com/?add-to-cart=651&amp;variation_id=652&amp;attribute_size=Extra+Large"></div></div><a class="reset_variations" href="#">Clear</a>      </td>
     </tr>
       </tbody>
  <div class="mobile-only" id="drop"><select id="size"><option>Small</option><option>Medium</option><option>Large</option><option>Extra Large</option></select></div></table>

  
  <div class="single_variation_wrap">
   <div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation" style="">
 <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">
  
 </div>

 <div class="woocommerce-variation-price">
  
 </div>

 <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">
  <p class="stock in-stock">In stock</p>

 </div>
</div><div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled">
 
    <div class="quantity_select" style="float: left;">
        <select name="quantity" class="qty" title="Qantity">
                            <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
    </div> <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>
 <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="651">
 <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="651">
 <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="653">
</div>
  </div>

   
 </form>

</div>
```

Here's the same form with another option selected:

```html
<div class="av-woo-purchase-button  avia-builder-el-16  el_after_av_hr  avia-builder-el-last "><p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>25.00</span></p>
<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="651" data-product_variations="[{&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;attribute_size&quot;:&quot;Extra Large&quot;},&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;<p class=\&quot;stock in-stock\&quot;>In stock<\/p>\n&quot;,&quot;backorders_allowed&quot;:false,&quot;dimensions&quot;:&quot;N\/A&quot;,&quot;dimensions_html&quot;:&quot;N\/A&quot;,&quot;display_price&quot;:25,&quot;display_regular_price&quot;:25,&quot;image&quot;:{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina.png&quot;,&quot;alt&quot;:&quot;Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina&quot;,&quot;src&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-450x431.png&quot;,&quot;srcset&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-450x431.png 450w, https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-300x288.png 300w, https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-768x736.png 768w, https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-505x484.png 505w, https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina.png 960w&quot;,&quot;sizes&quot;:&quot;(max-width: 450px) 100vw, 450px&quot;,&quot;full_src&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina.png&quot;,&quot;full_src_w&quot;:960,&quot;full_src_h&quot;:920,&quot;thumb_src&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-120x120.png&quot;,&quot;thumb_src_w&quot;:120,&quot;thumb_src_h&quot;:120,&quot;src_w&quot;:450,&quot;src_h&quot;:431},&quot;image_id&quot;:&quot;5823&quot;,&quot;is_downloadable&quot;:false,&quot;is_in_stock&quot;:true,&quot;is_purchasable&quot;:true,&quot;is_sold_individually&quot;:&quot;no&quot;,&quot;is_virtual&quot;:false,&quot;max_qty&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;min_qty&quot;:1,&quot;price_html&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sku&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;variation_description&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;variation_id&quot;:652,&quot;variation_is_active&quot;:true,&quot;variation_is_visible&quot;:true,&quot;weight&quot;:&quot;.3 lbs&quot;,&quot;weight_html&quot;:&quot;.3 lbs&quot;,&quot;step&quot;:1,&quot;input_value&quot;:1},{&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;attribute_size&quot;:&quot;Large&quot;},&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;<p class=\&quot;stock in-stock\&quot;>In stock<\/p>\n&quot;,&quot;backorders_allowed&quot;:false,&quot;dimensions&quot;:&quot;N\/A&quot;,&quot;dimensions_html&quot;:&quot;N\/A&quot;,&quot;display_price&quot;:25,&quot;display_regular_price&quot;:25,&quot;image&quot;:{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina.png&quot;,&quot;alt&quot;:&quot;Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina&quot;,&quot;src&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-450x431.png&quot;,&quot;srcset&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-450x431.png 450w, https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-300x288.png 300w, https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-768x736.png 768w, https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-505x484.png 505w, https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina.png 960w&quot;,&quot;sizes&quot;:&quot;(max-width: 450px) 100vw, 450px&quot;,&quot;full_src&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina.png&quot;,&quot;full_src_w&quot;:960,&quot;full_src_h&quot;:920,&quot;thumb_src&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/madcapcoffee.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Madcap-VNeckTee-Grid-Retina-120x120.png&quot;,&quot;thumb_src_w&quot;:120,&quot;thumb_src_h&quot;:120,&quot;src_w&quot;:450,&quot;src_h&quot;:431},&quot;image_id&quot;:&quot;5823&quot;,&quot;is_downloadable&quot;:false,&quot;is_in_stock&quot;:true,&quot;is_purchasable&quot;:true,&quot;is_sold_individually&quot;:&quot;no&quot;,&quot;is_virtual&quot;:false,&quot;max_qty&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;min_qty&quot;:1,&quot;price_html&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sku&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;variation_description&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;variation_id&quot;:653,&quot;variation_is_active&quot;:true,&quot;variation_is_visible&quot;:true,&quot;weight&quot;:&quot;.3 lbs&quot;,&quot;weight_html&quot;:&quot;.3 lbs&quot;,&quot;step&quot;:1,&quot;input_value&quot;:1}]" current-image="5823">
 
   <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
         <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="size">Size</label></td>
            <td class="value">
       <div class="desktop-only" id="radio"><div><input type="radio" name="attribute_size" value="Small" id="size_v_Small" disabled="disabled"><label for="size_v_Small">Small</label><input type="hidden" name="radio_variation_id" value="655"><input type="hidden" class="add-to-cart-url" value="https://madcapcoffee.com/?add-to-cart=651&amp;variation_id=655&amp;attribute_size=Small"></div><div><input type="radio" name="attribute_size" value="Medium" id="size_v_Medium" disabled="disabled"><label for="size_v_Medium">Medium</label><input type="hidden" name="radio_variation_id" value="654"><input type="hidden" class="add-to-cart-url" value="https://madcapcoffee.com/?add-to-cart=651&amp;variation_id=654&amp;attribute_size=Medium"></div><div><input type="radio" name="attribute_size" value="Large" id="size_v_Large" checked="checked"><label for="size_v_Large">Large</label><input type="hidden" name="radio_variation_id" value="653"><input type="hidden" class="add-to-cart-url" value="https://madcapcoffee.com/?add-to-cart=651&amp;variation_id=653&amp;attribute_size=Large"></div><div><input type="radio" name="attribute_size" value="Extra Large" id="size_v_Extra Large"><label for="size_v_Extra Large">Extra Large</label><input type="hidden" name="radio_variation_id" value="652"><input type="hidden" class="add-to-cart-url" value="https://madcapcoffee.com/?add-to-cart=651&amp;variation_id=652&amp;attribute_size=Extra+Large"></div></div><a class="reset_variations" href="#" style="visibility: visible; display: inline;">Clear</a>      </td>
     </tr>
       </tbody>
  <div class="mobile-only" id="drop"><select id="size"><option>Small</option><option>Medium</option><option>Large</option><option>Extra Large</option></select></div></table>

  
  <div class="single_variation_wrap">
   <div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation" style="">
 <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">
  
 </div>

 <div class="woocommerce-variation-price">
  
 </div>

 <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">
  <p class="stock in-stock">In stock</p>

 </div>
</div><div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled">
 
    <div class="quantity_select" style="float: left;">
        <select name="quantity" class="qty" title="Qantity">
                            <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
    </div> <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>
 <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="651">
 <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="651">
 <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="652">
</div>
  </div>

   
 </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value of selected radio button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839169/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button)

Comment: You need to post your code, we can't tell what you're doing wrong from this vague description.

Comment: @jmargolisvt It's also used for radio buttons, to tell which one is selected.

Comment: @jmargolisvt So if I want to change the state of that radio might I do .checked(); instead of attr('checked', 'checked'); ? Because I need to change a property rather than an attribute?

Comment: I don't think it matters if you use attrs or props, but I prefer attrs because they are visible right in the markup.  One thing that might be getting you is that there is no effective difference between `checked` and `checked="checked"`.  If the prop/attr is there at all, it's checked.

Answer (score 0):

Because clicking on the radio input whose `.val()` matches the selected option's `.text()`, I just passed a `.click()` from the option to its matching radio button.