# direct users according to user response when either of radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, html

I have created a Multipage form using PHP, HTML5 and JS, On first step there are two radio button called A and B, I want to redirect user to step 3 present in a  tag when user clicks on radio button A and if user clicks on radio button B it should redirect them to Step 4 present in  tag so basically it depends on user response

This is the form code

---

```html
<div class="formbox">
    <a name="get_started"></a>
    <form id="a" name="a" action="http://www.webtechevolution.com/quixfi/choose-offers/" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="a_aid">
        <div class="box" id="step1">
            <div class="box_in">
                <div class="header">Get Started</div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h2 class="title">How would you rate your credit?</h2></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="cc-selector">
                            <input id="credit_bad" type="radio" name="credit" class="credit" value="bad" <?php echo $credit == "bad" ? "checked" : ""; ?> />
                            <label class="drinkcard-cc credit_bad" for="credit_bad">Bad</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="cc-selector">
                            <input id="credit_fair" type="radio" name="credit" class="credit" value="fair" <?php echo $credit == "fair" ? "checked" : ""; ?> />
                            <label class="drinkcard-cc credit_fair" for="credit_fair">Fair</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="cc-selector">
                            <input id="credit_good" type="radio" name="credit" class="credit" value="good" <?php echo $credit == "good" ? "checked" : ""; ?> />
                            <label class="drinkcard-cc credit_good" for="credit_good">Good</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="cc-selector">
                            <input id="credit_excellent" type="radio" name="credit" class="credit" value="excellent" <?php echo $credit == "excellent" ? "checked" : ""; ?> />
                            <label class="drinkcard-cc credit_excellent" for="credit_excellent">Excellent</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="step2">
            <div class="box_in">
                <div class="header">Almost Finished!</div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h2 class="title">Do you have an active checking account?</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="cc-selector">
                            <input id="account_yes" type="radio" name="account" class="account" value="yes" <?php echo $account == "yes" ? "checked" : ""; ?> />
                            <label class="drinkcard-cc" for="account_yes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="cc-selector">
                            <input id="account_no" type="radio" name="account" class="account" value="no" <?php echo $account == "no" ? "checked" : ""; ?> />
                            <label class="drinkcard-cc" for="account_no">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="form-control">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <div class="cc-selector">
                            <button class="back">Back</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="step3">
            <div class="box_in">
                <div class="header">One Last Questions...</div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h2 class="title">Are you a small business owner?</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="cc-selector">
                            <input id="business_yes" type="radio" name="business" class="business" value="yes" <?php echo $business == "yes" ? "checked" : ""; ?> />
                            <label class="drinkcard-cc" for="business_yes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="cc-selector">
                            <input id="business_no" type="radio" name="business" class="business" value="no" <?php echo $business == "no" ? "checked" : ""; ?> />
                            <label class="drinkcard-cc " for="business_no">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <div class="cc-selector">
                            <button class="back">Back</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="step4">
            <div class="box-in">
                <div class="header">Get access to your search results now:</div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="form-control">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname ?>" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="form-control">
                            <Label>Last Name</Label>
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname ?>" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="form-control">
                            <label>Address</label>
                            <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $address ?>" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="form-control">
                            <Label>Zip code</Label>
                            <input type="text" name="zip" value="<?php echo $zip ?>" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="form-control">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="form-control">
                            <Label>Phone</Label>
                            <input type="tel" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone ?>" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="form-control" style="padding-top:10px;">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Yes" name="term" id="term" />
                            <label for="term">By checking this box you agree that you are a US Resident over the age 18 and agree to the <a href="">Privacy Policy</a> and <a href="">Terms & Conditions</a>.</label>
                            <input type="submit" class="ak_submit" value="SEARCH for sponcered listings">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <div class="cc-selector">
                            <button class="back">Back</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

What should i do ?

Comment: you can check wich one is check and do the redirect using JS, to better help you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839312/5877632

Comment: Here I have to call a div containing the whole form? so how to call that <div> tag