# Get Value of selected radio button in HTML Service back to Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a table I've created to pop up in my Google Sheet file via HTML Service UI that has a radio button listed before each row in the table.  I am looking to get the value of the selected radio button chosen by the user, and turn into a variable for a separate server side apps script I am looking to execute 'onClick' in of the chosen radio button.  I am having difficulty, though, pulling back the value of the selected radio button with the current iteration of my code (shown below).  Let me know what I am missing.  Is it possible to avoid a for loop to get at the selected value?

```
function htmlOrders() {
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = active.getSheetByName("POHistory");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:K" + lastRow); 
  var data = myRange.getDisplayValues();
  var optionsHTML = "";
  var seenType = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     if(seenType[data[i][0]]) {
       continue;}
   seenType[data[i][0]] = true;
   optionsHTML += "<tr>";
   optionsHTML += "<td><input type='radio' name='selectedPO' value='" + data[i][0] + "' onclick='google.apps.script.run.editPO()';></td>";
   optionsHTML += "</tr>"
}
return optionsHTML;}  

function editPO(){
  var x = document.table.selectedPO.value;
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('editPO').evaluate();
  html.setHeight(600).setWidth(800);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .showModalDialog(html, 'Edit PO' + x);
}
```

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="table" id="table">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Edit?</th>
    <th>PO No.</th>
  </tr>
   <?!= htmlOrders(); ?>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839312/7215091).

Comment: Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839169/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button).

Answer (score 1):

Have a read on the [dialog method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String)) you called. As explained in the documentation, the server side script is not suspended with this method and you need to make asynchronous calls. In other words, after showing your custom dialog, your script stops running (as that is the last action it does).

You will need to use [google.script.run in your HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) in order to call a new function, and you can pass any variables you wish from that HTML