# Javascript querySelector get value condition

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I am trying to get value from input radio button with querySelector, but I want to write condition "if input is checked = console log is input value, but if input is not checked = console log is 0"

My code is:

```
function getVal(){

    var firstVal= document.querySelector("input[name='price1']:checked");
    if (firstVal.checked){
       console.log(firstVal.value);

    } 
}
```

If i call function getVal now i get value from checked input.

but i tried to write this :

```
function getVal(){

    var firstVal= document.querySelector("input[name='price1']:checked");
    if (firstVal.checked){
        console.log(firstVal.value);
    } else 
        console.log(0);
    }
}
```

but program not working console log shows nothing.

Then i tried

```
function getVal(){

    var firstVal= document.querySelector("input[name='price1']:checked");
    if (firstVal.checked){
          console.log(firstVal.value);
    } 

    if (firstVal.checked === false){
          console.log(0);
    }

}
```

And still program not working. Console log shows nothing.

My HTML code is:

```
<label for="test1">test1</label>
<input type="radio" name="price1" id="test1" value="1" onchange="showPrice();">
<label for="test2">test2</label>
<input type="radio" name="price1" id="test2" value="2" onchange="showPrice()">
<label for="test3">test3</label>
<input type="radio" name="price1" id="test3" value="3" onchange="showPrice()">
<label for="test4">test4</label>
<input type="radio" name="price1" id="test4" value="4" onchange="showPrice()">
</div>
```

Edit

I use querySelectorAll and I fixed it.

If is not checked input radio, value in console is 0.
If is checked input radio, you get value from checked radio.

Here is my new code

```js
        function getVal() {
            var firstVal = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='price1']");

              if (firstVal[0].checked){
                  console.log(firstVal[0].value);
              }   
              if (firstVal[1].checked){
                  console.log(firstVal[1].value);
              }
              if (firstVal[2].checked){
                  console.log(firstVal[2].value);
              }
              if (firstVal[3].checked){
                  console.log(firstVal[3].value);
              }

              if(firstVal[0].checked === false && firstVal[1].checked === false && firstVal[2].checked === false && firstVal[3].checked === false){
                  console.log(0);
              }

        }
```

```html
  <button onclick="getVal()">test</button><div class="priceInput">
      <label for="test1">test1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="price1" id="test1" value="1">
      <label for="test2">test2</label>
      <input type="radio" name="price1" id="test2" value="2">
      <label for="test3">test3</label>
      <input type="radio" name="price1" id="test3" value="3">
      <label for="test4">test4</label>
      <input type="radio" name="price1" id="test4" value="4">
```

But still I dont understand why I didnt get value with this code:

```
function getVal(){

    var firstVal= document.querySelector("input[name='price1']:checked");
    if (firstVal.checked){
          console.log(firstVal.value);
    } 

    if (firstVal.checked === false){
          console.log(0);
    }

}
```

Thank for help guys. Herectic Monkey solved it.

Final code:

```
function getVal(){

var firstVal= document.querySelector("input[name='price1']:checked");
if (firstVal) { 
    console.log(firstVal.value); 
} else { 
    console.log(0); 
}

}
```

Comment: If you use a selector ending in `:checked`, you will only find the checked inputs to begin with. So `firstVal.checked` is obsolete. firstVal will always be checked due to the `input[name='price1']:checked` selector finding the first checked input or null. So your else clause will never trigger as written.

Comment: A couple notes: You don't have a function created called showPrice but it is referenced in onchange. and you use :checked in your querySelector then repeat in your IF, remove it from querySelector.

Comment: Where is code for `showPrice`

Comment: Is it the answer you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888836/javascript-queryselector-get-value-condition/54889100#54889100

Comment: Shilly i know but i tried to remove :checked from queryselector and now i can get only value from first input. I tried to use querySelectorAll but i get always all inputs in node list

Comment: Just use `if (firstVal) { console.log(firstVal.value); } else { console.log(0); }`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value of selected radio button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839169/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button)

Comment: Heretic Monkey thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it using jQuery very simple,

```js
$('.test').change(function(){

   var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
   
   console.log(isChecked ? $(this).val() : 0);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="test1">test1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test1" class="test" value="1">
<label for="test2">test2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test2" class="test" value="2">
<label for="test3">test3</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test3" class="test" value="3">
<label for="test4">test4</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="test4" class="test" value="4">
```

Comment: If you remove showPrice and call getval it is the same. But still does not show 0 value if is not checked any input

Comment: Check my latest answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888836/javascript-queryselector-get-value-condition/54889100#54889100