# How to get the value of a radio button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I created an admin page where I input values of similar type='name' which will pop up on submit to another page as radio buttons. But I'm getting an error 'cannot read property value of null' from the console on the page where the radio buttons are been posted.

```
let answer = document.querySelector('input[name="choice"]:checked').value;
```

Comment: Why are you doing it with a query selector like this? The whole point of a radio button is that multiple radios with the same name take on a single value; so for instance, if the radio is in a form named `testForm`, you could just do `document.testForm.choice.value` to get the currently checked value. No query selector needed.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk If the `querySelector` returns null, your approach won't work as well...

Comment: Maybe, though there might be a reason the query selector is returning null that won't break the usual named approach. Hard to tell without seeing the HTML. (It might just be that none of the radio options are checked yet, in which case the named approach at least won't throw any errors.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value of selected radio button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839169/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var radios = document.getElementsByName('genderS');

for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        // do whatever you want with the checked radio
        alert(radios[i].value);

        // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
        break;
    }
}
```

```html
<label for="gender">Gender: </label>
<input type="radio" name="genderS" value="1" checked="checked">Male</input>
<input type="radio" name="genderS" value="0" >Female</input>
```

Comment: Its a quiz app actually where I have the admin page to input the question and options

<p>Question: <textarea type="text" id="question"></textarea></p>
    <p>Option 1: <input type="text" id="option1"></p>
    <p>Option 2: <input type="text" id="option2"></p>
    <p>Option 3: <input type="text" id="option3"></p>
    <p>Option 4: <input type="text" id="option4"></p>
    <p>Answer: <input type="text" id="answer"></p>

Comment: And the question page to populate the inputs where the options are in radio buttons

<h4 >{{question}}</h4>
        <input type='radio' id="r1" value="opt1" name='choice'>{{option1}}</input><br>
        <input type='radio' id="r2" value="opt2" name='choice'>{{option2}}</input><br>
        <input type='radio' id="r3" value="opt3" name='choice'>{{option3}}</input><br>
        <input type='radio' id="r4" value="opt4" name='choice'>{{option4}}</input><br>
        <p style="display:none" id="r5" value="opt5" >{{answer}}</p>

Comment: So I'm trying to compare the value of the checked button on each question to the value of the answer. So I think I need to work on the id of each entry

Comment: replace question values from static to {{option1}} and try again

https://jsfiddle.net/0eoxpLck/7

Answer (score 0):

The snippet that you provided should work. It does assume that there are input fields in HTML that:

1. have `name="choice"`, and
2. has been checked

Without seeing the HTML, it's hard to say, but maybe look for a typo in the HTML.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const radio = document.querySelector('input[name="choice"]:checked');
  if (radio) {
    const answer = radio.value;
    console.log(`choice ${answer}`);
  } else {
    console.log('no choice');
  }
});
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="1" /> One</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="2" /> Two</label>
<div>
  <button id="button">Click</button>
</div>
```