# Adding a row to a table using information the user submitted (HTML/JS)

Tags: javascript, html

On my first HTML page, I ask the user to submit some information:

```
    <form>
    <label for="task">New Task</label>
    <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="Enter here">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="deadline">Deadline</label>
    <input type="date" id="deadline" name="deadline">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="duration">Duration</label>
    <input type="text" id="duration" name="duration" placeholder="__ hours">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="priority">Priority</label>
    <input type="radio" id="A" name="priority" value="A">
    <label for="A">A</label>
    <input type="radio" id="B" name="priority" value="B">
    <label for="B">B</label>
    <input type="radio" id="C" name="priority" value="C">
    <label for="C">C</label> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id ="submit" value="Submit" onclick="addRow()">
    </form>
```

On my second HTML page, I display some of that information in a table.

```
    <table id="todayTasks">
    <tr>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Task</th>
    <th>Hours Needed</th>
    <th>Priority</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
    function addRow(){
        var table = document.getElementById("todayTasks");
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        var td2 = document.createElement('td');
        var td3 = document.createElement('td');
        td1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('task').value;
        td2.innerHTML = document.getElementById('duration').value;
        td3.innerHTML = document.getElementById('priority').value;
        row.appendChild(td1);
        row.appendChild(td2);
        row.appendChild(td3);
        table.children[0].appendChild(row);
    }
```

I'm really new to HTML and JavaScript, and I'm not really sure what I'm doing. When I try submitting the form, the table isn't updated. Any tips?

Comment: Going wrong here `document.getElementById('priority').value` as there can't be duplicate `id`s. Use `td3.innerHTML = document.querySelector('input[name="priority"]:checked')? document.querySelector('input[name="priority"]:checked').value: ''`

Answer (score 0):

Use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` in your Submit form button.

`<input type="submit" id ="submit" value="Submit" onclick="addRow()">`

As the name suggests `type="submit"` is expecting a destination where your form can get submitted.
Wherein `type="button"` is waiting for some event to occur like a button click.
So button input has `onclick` event listeners and submit buttons have `onsubmit` event listeners.

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ys8zv4aja/16/). Implemented in both ways.

Also, your logic to read the values of radio needs correction. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839169/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button) are a few answers that might help you to read the radio button values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to JavaScript as well, but I think I've come up with a solution.

Firstly, I changed your HTML.
I created a new class called "priorities" for each of the radio buttons, that way, they're grouped together nicely. I deleted the IDs that you had for them as well. I've also added a new input field for "Actions".

Secondly, I rearranged your Table to have both a thead and tbody section to separate the table headers from the table body. We will be adding rows to the table body in this case. Because of this, I deleted your "todayTasks" ID from the table and instead added a new ID to the table body called "tableBody".

Third, I placed row in the table body just so I could visualize what was going on. I've added some CSS to make it look cleaner as well.

Now onto the JavaScript.

I created one large eventListener on the submit button of the form to accomplish everything. Each line of JavaScript should have a comment in the code below.

I'm PRETTY sure I could've simplified the JavaScript code below, but I'm still fairly new to JavaScript as well. If anyone can optimize is, please let me know!

```js
// Creates an event listener when the form is submitted.
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  // Here we are just getting the values given by the user.
  const task = document.getElementById("task").value;
  const action = document.getElementById("action").value;
  const deadline = document.getElementById("deadline").value;
  const duration = document.getElementById("duration").value;
  const priorities = document.getElementsByClassName("priorities");

  // priorities is different from the other input fields because
  // they are radio elements.

  // For each element with the class of "priorities",
  for (const priority of priorities) {
    // check if that element is "checked".
    if (priority.checked) {
      // If "checked", set its value to the var "selectedPriority".
      var selectedPriority = priority.value;
    }
  }

  // Here we are creating a new row with the above values.

  // Create 5 unique table items, 1 for each heading
  // I'm not sure what you wanted under Status and Actions, so I made my own content up.
  // By default, the status value will be set to "Incomplete".
  const tableItem1 = document.createElement("td");
  const status = document.createTextNode("Incomplete");
  tableItem1.appendChild(status);

  const tableItem2 = document.createElement("td");
  const taskItem = document.createTextNode(task);
  tableItem2.appendChild(taskItem);

  const tableItem3 = document.createElement("td");
  const hoursItem = document.createTextNode(duration);
  tableItem3.appendChild(hoursItem);

  const tableItem4 = document.createElement("td");
  const priorityItem = document.createTextNode(selectedPriority);
  tableItem4.appendChild(priorityItem);


  const tableItem5 = document.createElement("td");
  const actionItem = document.createTextNode(action);
  tableItem5.appendChild(actionItem);


  // Create an array for these new table items.
  const newTableItems = [
    tableItem1,
    tableItem2,
    tableItem3,
    tableItem4,
    tableItem5,
  ];

  // Create 1 row
  const row = document.createElement("tr");

  // Add the 5 table items to the 1 row
  for (tableItem of newTableItems) {
    row.appendChild(tableItem);
  }

  // Add the row to the end of the table body
  const table = document.getElementById("tableBody");
  table.appendChild(row);

  // This is so the default "submit" action doesn't occur.
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
th {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
td {
  padding: 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Stack Overflow</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <label for="task">New Task</label>
    <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="Enter here" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label for="task">New Action</label>
    <input type="text" id="action" placeholder="Enter here" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label for="deadline">Deadline</label>
    <input type="date" id="deadline" name="deadline" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label for="duration">Duration</label>
    <input type="text" id="duration" name="duration" placeholder="__ hours" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label for="priority">Priority</label>
    <input type="radio" class="priorities" name="priority" value="A" />
    <label for="A">A</label>
    <input type="radio" class="priorities" name="priority" value="B" />
    <label for="B">B</label>
    <input type="radio" class="priorities" name="priority" value="C" />
    <label for="C">C</label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

  <table id="todayTasks">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>Duration</th>
        <th>Priority</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
      <tr>
        <td>Incomplete</td>
        <td>Walk the dog</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>Get leash</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```