# are there some built-in function like onclick for radio input?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have three radio inputs and I want to let the radio inputs return the value of the `inputs` uand execute a function when user selects one option.

Here is the code:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('input[name="radios"]:checked').value);
```

```html
 <form>
 <input type="radio"  id='HTML'name="radios" value="HTML">HTML<br>
<input type="radio" id="css" name="radios"  value="CSS">CSS<br>
<input type="radio" id="javascript" name="radios" value="JavaScript">Javascript<br>
</form>
```

Thanks for the answer from [Parthik Gosar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839169/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button/15839451), I could get the value from `radio input`.

But the problem is `document.querySelector('input[name="radios"]:checked').value` will get the value from the `radio input` once the page loaded which is `null`.

I just wonder is there some built-in function similar to `onclick` where it will execute a function when user select an option or other ways to solve the problem?

Thanks for any responds!

*I know we could use `document.getElementById('').checked` to check, but it will execute the function when the page loaded which will not work for me.,

Comment: Just move your JS code after radio buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are* looking for a click listener. Just attach one listener to the form element ([event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) allows you to add a listener to a parent element and capture events from child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM), and pick up the value of the clicked button and log it.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

// Because you're using event delegation the parent
// will watch for _all_ events from its children.
// So if you only want to watch for events from
// just the input buttons you need to grab the nodeName
// of the clicked element and then check to see if
// it's an input button before you do anything else
function handleClick(e) {
  const { nodeName, value } = e.target;
  if (nodeName === 'INPUT') {
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" id='HTML' name="radios" value="HTML">HTML<br>
  <input type="radio" id="css" name="radios" value="CSS">CSS<br>
  <input type="radio" id="javascript" name="radios" value="JavaScript">Javascript<br>
</form>
```

Comment: It is very helpful, but the only problem is that if I just click on the text (Javascript/Css/HTML), the function will execute as well and will return `undefined`. Is there way that is could avoid this happens?

Comment: @Sahil answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your initialization code in a listener that fires after the page has loaded (or just put your javascript at the bottom of the page under the HTML).

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ... init code
})
```

Also, you can use a conditional `?` in case there isn't a checked value

```
  console.log(document.querySelector('input[name="radios"]:checked')?.value);
```

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  console.log(document.querySelector('input[name="radios"]:checked')?.value);
})
```

```html
 <form>
 <input type="radio"  id='HTML'name="radios" value="HTML">HTML<br>
<input type="radio" id="css" name="radios"  value="CSS">CSS<br>
<input type="radio" id="javascript" checked name="radios" value="JavaScript">Javascript<br>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think this will automactially give the value to `Javascript`. Is there way to solve this problem?