On Radio Button select, select dropdown option with same value
I created 2 input, one is Radio Button, and one is Dropdown. I want user to click on radio button and it will select the option in the dropdown with the same value.
How can I do this with JS, not using Jquery?
Please help me with this.
Thank you!
My sample code:
   <p class="line-item-property__field">
       <label>Color</label><br>
       <input type="radio" name="color" value="1"> <span>1</span><br>
       <input type="radio" name="color" value="2"> <span>2</span><br>
       <input type="radio" name="color" value="3"> <span>3</span><br>
   </p>

   <p class="line-item-property__field">
        <label>Color</label><br>
         <select id="your-name" name="dropdown-color">
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </p>


What have you tried yourself? Where are you stuck? [ask]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839169/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-selected-radio-button  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript and finally: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users


Use event delegation. This will allow you to add one listener to a parent element of the radio buttons to "catch" events from them as they bubble up the DOM.

The listener will call a function. First it will check that the event from the element that fired it is one of the radio buttons. Second it will assign that element's value as the select element's value.


(In this example I've modified your sample markup slightly to use a fieldset element, and proper input labelling, which is perhaps more in line with the UI you're trying to achieve.)


// Cache the fieldset element, and the select element
const fieldset = document.querySelector('fieldset');
const select = document.querySelector('#your-name');

// Add a listener to the fieldset element that watches
// for changes among it or its child elements
fieldset.addEventListener('change', handleChange);

// When a change event happens
function handleChange(e) {

  // If the element that fired the event has a
  // name attribute of "color"
  if (e.target.closest('[name="color"]')) {

    // Change the select value to match that
    // changed element's value
    select.value = e.target.value;
  }
}
body > section ~ section { margin-top: 1rem; }
<section class="line-item-property__field">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Color</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="1" checked>1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="2">2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="3">3</label>
  </fieldset>
</section>

<section class="line-item-property__field">
  <select id="your-name" name="dropdown-color">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</section>



Additional documentation

closest

querySelector

addEventListener

Event target



Thank you guys for helping me with this. I also found a way to do this with Jquery. Just posting here in case anyone need it.


$('.select-color, input[name="color"]').change(updateElements);

function updateElements(e) {
    var valueAttribute = '[value="' + e.target.value + '"]';
    $('.select-color option' + valueAttribute).prop('selected', true);
    $('input[name="color"]' + valueAttribute).prop('checked', true);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select name="color" class="select-color">
        <option value="1" selected>Red</option>
        <option value="2">Green</option>
        <option value="3">Blue</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="1" checked="checked" />Red
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="2" />Green
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="3" />Blue
    <br />
</form>



