# When using DOM within a loop: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null error

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom, radio-button

Hi im having trouble with a bit of code checking if any of the radio buttons are checked
im getting this result:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null
 when I run it
the code that is relevant to this is:

```
function validateForm() {
 var msg="";
 var LoE="";
 ...some code
 for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
 if ((document.getElementById('"LoE" + i').checked)){
     LoE="";
     break;
     }
 Else
     {
      result = false;
      msg+="You need to chose your level of entry";
      }
 }
 ...some more code
}
```

and the radio buttons that are being checked. They are within a form by the name of ExamEntry

```
 <tr>

 <td><input type = "radio" name = "LevelOfEntry" id = "LoE0" value = "GCSE">GCSE</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>

 <td><input type = "radio" name = "LevelOfEntry" id = "LoE1" value = "AS">AS</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>

 <td><input type = "radio" name = "LevelOfEntry" id = "LoE2" value = "A2">A2</td>

 </tr>
```

thanks for the help.

EDIT
removed the single quote marks as suggested in the comments and replaced with:

```
   if ((document.getElementById("LoE" + i).checked)){
```

now only getting error that else is unspecified in this part of the code:

```
    Else
     {
      result = false;
      msg+="You need to chose your level of entry";
      }
    }
```

EDIT:
resolved. Thanks a lot everyone

Comment: document.getElementById(' "LoE" + i ') you know that's a string, right?? remove the single quotes.. and it may work.. ._.

Comment: yeah.. thanks to you too.. o_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a note and I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but you are limiting yourself in terms of specifying the amount of radio buttons and using the ID instead of the name.

Making use of [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) makes working with radio buttons a lot easier (just saying), alternatively this is a more robust way in terms of this post:

```
function get_radio_value() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByName("selected");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      if (inputs[i].checked) {
        return inputs[i].value;
      }
    }
}

function onSubmit() {
    var id = get_radio_value();
    alert("selected input is: " + id);
}
```

See this link: [getting selected value of radio button in case of action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492928/getting-selected-value-of-radio-button-in-case-of-action?answertab=votes#tab-top)