# get selected value of radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Javascript. I have a code snippet like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" onchange="onCompChange()">
                        <div class="radio" id = "compSelect">
                            <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">op1</label>
                            </br>
                            <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">op2</label>
                            </br>
                            <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">op3</label>
                        </div>
 </ul>
```

On selecting a radio button, I want to know which option is selected (op1/op2/op3).

Comment: You need to search the site first before posting this. Check [this query](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+selected+value+of+radio+button) out, for example.

Comment: your html is invalid the child of a ***ul is li***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting selected value of radio button in case of action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492928/getting-selected-value-of-radio-button-in-case-of-action)

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the selected radioName item of a form with id myForm:
`$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()`
Here's an example:

```
$('#myForm input').on('change', function() {
   var value = $('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val(); 
   console.log(value);
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="3" /> 3 <br />
</form>
```

Think this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<input type="radio" name="opt radio" onclick="check(this.value)" value="op1" >op1</label>
<input type="radio" name="opt radio" onclick="check(this.value)" value="op2" >op2</label>
<input type="radio" name="opt radio" onclick="check(this.value)" value="op3" >op3</label>
```

in your .js:

```
        function check(value) {
            //... use your value
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" >
                        <div class="radio" id = "compSelect">
                            <label><input onchange="onCompChange(this)" type="radio" name="optradio">op1</label>
                            </br>
                            <label><input onchange="onCompChange(this)" type="radio" name="optradio">op2</label>
                            </br>
                            <label><input onchange="onCompChange(this)" type="radio" name="optradio">op3</label>
                        </div>
 </ul>  

<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">

  function onCompChange(radio){
   
   var content = radio.parentElement.innerHTML;
  var output = content.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
  alert(output);
 

}       

</script>
```