# PHP / AJAX form, handling radio selection

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, radio-button

I have a form similar the following:

```
<form id='myForm'>
  <input type='text' name='notes' id='notes'>
  <input type='radio' name='select' value='1'>
  <input type='radio' name='select' value='2'>
  <input type='submit' onclick='processForm( getElementByID('notes').value, ? )'>
</form>
```

The form is processed via AJAX. I don't know what to place in the second argument of the processForm() function (where I've placed a '?'). I need the value of the radio selection (the radios are mutually exclusive).

Below is prototype for processForm() function:

```
function processForm(notes, selection){
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("display_results").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","process_form.php?notes="+notes+"&sel="+selection,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This question differs from  others such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492928/getting-selected-value-of-radio-button-in-case-of-action) as it has a submit button with an 'onclick' attribute that executes a function.

Comment: Foggy question I see

Comment: That depends entirely on your `processForm` function. What does that function do / look like?

Comment: I've added the prototype.